# In Parsec, how do I run second parser, only if the first parser consumed some input?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I need a combinator like `p1 << p2`, but `p2` should run **only** if `p1` has succeeded and **consumed some input**.

If `p1` succeeded without consuming input, `p2` should not run.

If `p1` failed, then `p2` is also ignored?

Overall result is `r1`'s result

Comment: Parsec allows you to access the current source location, so you could measure it before and after `p1` and see if it's the same

Comment: Otherwise it seems like a refactor of your grammar might be in order.  So split `p1` into `p1Empty` and `p1'`, and use `p1' <|> (p1Empty << p2)`, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Parsec primitives make an internal distinction between a parser that succeeds after consuming some input and a parser that succeeds after consuming no input which you should be able to leverage.  In particular, the following ought to work to parse `p` and then -- conditioned on `p` successfully consuming input -- parse `q` and discard its results:

```
ifConsumed :: Monad m => ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m b -> ParsecT s u m a
ifConsumed p q = mkPT k
  where -- k :: State s u -> m (Consumed (m (Reply s u a)))
        k s = do cons <- runParsecT p s
                 case cons of
                   Consumed mrep -> do
                     rep <- mrep
                     case rep of
                       Ok x s' err -> runParsecT (fmap (const x) q) s'
                       Error err -> return . Consumed . return $ Error err
                   Empty mrep -> do
                     rep <- mrep
                     case rep of
                       Ok x s' err -> return . Empty . return $ Ok x s' err
                       Error err -> return . Empty . return $ Error err
```

It's ugly because Parsec doesn't directly expose the `ParsecT` constructor, so you have to use the `mkPt` and `runParsecT` intermediaries which add a lot of boilerplate.

In a nutshell, it runs the `p` parser.  If this succeeds with input consumed (the `Consumed -> Ok` branch), it runs the `q` parser modified via `fmap` to return the value parsed by `p`.  On the other hand, if `p` succeeds with no input consumed (the `Empty -> Ok` branch), it simply returns success without running the `q` parser.

The only caveat is that I'm not 100% sure how, within the Parsec library itself, the invariant is preserved whereby the `Consumed -> Ok` branch only gets called when input has been consumed, so I don't know if this is truly reliable.  You'll want to test it carefully in your particular use case.

For the following parser --- which parses a list of one or more elements separated commas where each element consists of zero or more digits, then two exclamation marks only if the previous parser consumed some input, then a semicolon --- it seems to work:

```
p :: Parser [String]
p = ifConsumed (sepBy1 (many digit) (char ',')) (char '!' >> char '!') <* char ';'

runp :: String -> Either ParseError [String]
runp = parse p ""
```

Some tests:

```
runp ""         -- fails, expecting semicolon
runp ";"        -- returns [""]
runp "!!;"      -- fails, "!!" w/ no preceding content
runp ",;"       -- fails, missing "!!"
runp ",!!;"     -- returns ["",""]
runp ",!;"      -- fails, expecting second "!"
runp ",1,23;"   -- fails, missing "!!"
runp ",1,23!!;"  -- returns ["","1","23"]
```

Answer (score 1):

With a naive parser implementation, you should be able to do this:

```
(<<) p1 p2 = P $ \inp -> case parse p1 inp of
  ErrorResult e -> ErrorResult e
  SuccessResult (rem, res) -> if rem == inp
    then SuccessResult (rem, res)
    else parse p2 rem
```

Though Parsec is more advanced, you could probably roll your own there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that for arbitrary parsers `p1` and `p2`: you need them to communicate somehow. If you could do this, it seems to me that you would break referential transparency.

For example, consider parsing the input string `repeat 'x'`: whether `p1` consumes a character or not, `p2` will see the string as an endless sea of `x` characters. If it hasn't communicated with `p1` somehow (eg by modifying something in the parser's state), then you can't know whether a character was consumed; if your combinator were somehow able to treat these two cases differently, it would be breaking the rules.

Comment: I thought Parsec parsers , being Monads, allow such way of "communication"

Comment: Yes, the parsers may communicate with each other if they like. But your combinator can't reach inside an arbitrary other parser and force it to communicate, and it can't observe from the outside whether the parser has consumed anything.